# Having trouble with having an overlay appear over other views in SwiftUI. Does anyone have any ideas?

Tags: swiftui, dropdown, overlay

I'm currently working on trying to implement a custom dropdown menu in SwiftUI that displays a grid of buttons (1-16) and allows you to select one of them. I am using an overlay to display the dropdown below the corresponding button, and it seems to be functioning properly except it's displaying the dropdown below all of the other elements in the view. I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706674/how-to-put-view-on-top-of-all-other-views-in-swiftui) here regarding this issue and they used a ZStack to solve it, but I haven't been able to get the same success. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View { 
   @State var showDropdown = false
   @State var selected = 0
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Some Text")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: { showDropdown.toggle() }) {
                            Text(selected == 0 ? "Omni" : String(selected))
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 36)
                        }
                        .zIndex(1)
                        .overlay(
                            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                if self.showDropdown {
                                    Spacer(minLength: 26)
                                    DropdownMenu(selection: self.$selected)
                                } else {
                                    EmptyView()
                                }
                            }, alignment: .topLeading
                        )
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Some Text")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: { }) {
                            Text("Omni")
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 36)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Some Text")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: { }) {
                            Text("Omni")
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 36)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Some Text")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: { }) {
                            Text("Omni")
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 36)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

and here are some images of the results:

[Before Press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx53w.png)
[After Press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIkUe.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will other buttons also have dropdown or this is the only one?

Comment: Others will as well, yes. Everything you see as "Omni" on the example images.

Answer (score 0):

The `.zIndex` works for view in *same container*, so you need something like the following (or make custom flat layout container with all such buttons at same level, then rise clicked button atop).

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
    HStack {
        Text("Some Text")
            .lineLimit(1)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(action: { showDropdown.toggle() }) {
            Text(selected == 0 ? "Omni" : String(selected))
                .frame(width: 80, height: 36)
        }
        .zIndex(1)
        .overlay(
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                if self.showDropdown {
                    Spacer(minLength: 26)
                    DropdownMenu(selection: self.$selected)
                }
            }, alignment: .topLeading
        )
    }.zIndex(showDropdown ? 1 : 0)      // << this !!
    
    HStack {
        Text("Some Text")
            .lineLimit(1)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(action: { }) {
            Text("Omni")
                .frame(width: 80, height: 36)
        }
    }
}.zIndex(showDropdown ? 1 : 0)        // << and this !!
```