# How to properly present a popup view in SwiftUI (not as a sheet)?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would want to present a popup Slider in my iOS app. I'm currently using overlay like so:

```
.overlay(
    HStack {
        if isEditingValue {
            Slider(value: $valueToEdit)
                .offset(y: 90)
        }
    }
)
```

The problem is that any content after the view with the `.overlay`, will be drawn on top of the slider, that has been moved down with `.offset` so as not to obscure the value to be edited.

How can I get the popup Slider to be presented above all other content in correct relation to the view it will edit? I'm currently hiding all content below the value to be edited when the popup Slider is visible, which is not optimal.

Comment: Check this might be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/q/65883129/14733292

Comment: @Raja Kishan: that was useful, but it does not solve the problem of showing the popup so that is visually attached to a specific view. In other words I don't want the popup to always appear in the center of the screen, but directly below the view with the value to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

Within one view hierarchy this can be solved by `zIndex`, like

```
TargetView()
.overlay(
    HStack {
        if isEditingValue {
            Slider(value: $valueToEdit)
                .offset(y: 90)
        }
    }
)
.zIndex(1) // default is 0, so others will be below
//.zIndex(isEditingValue ? 1 : 0)    // as variant

// ... other sibling views
```

if view hierarchy is complex, then view with slider might be overlapped with view from different view hierarchy, and such case cannot be solved just by layout modifiers and needs to be solved at global level of your app UI design.

Comment: the exact problem is that the view will be overlapped by a view from a different view hierarchy: for example a sibling. I guess I will need to pass the view geometry of the view that the popup will be attached to up to a parent view, that can position the popup over everything else. Any examples or suggestions?

Comment: No, SwiftUI rendering engine, does not allow this, at least for now. I'll need to reindex all affected sub-hierarchies, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847909/12299030 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283907/12299030 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798786/12299030. Also, as variant, rethink UI as flat for views that has such overlays or change the order of construction so view with overlay will be at top.

Comment: what about PreferenceKey?

Comment: PreferenceKey only pass information/model from child to parents, it does not affect layout. If you want to separate slider form holder, then it might help to stick preference overlay at right place of sub-sub-child, but you will make with this hard coupling of entire screen layout and your component won't be reusable. Of course it is up to you.

Comment: I understand that PreferenceKey does not affect layout. I was thinking of storing geometry information of popup slider user views so the popup could be added at the root parent ZStack and be positioned using the passed geometries. I was thinking of a key-anchorpoint dictionary for looking up where the popup should be positioned. If it is in a root ZStack, it can be positioned over all else. Maybe the View would have a reference type property were the key-anchorpoints could be stored without retriggering view layout.

Comment: Maybe a view modifier that takes a Hashable argument, so the child view geometry can be stored with `(topAnchor: CGPoint, centerAnchor: CGPoint, bottomAnchor: CGPoint)`